# Display "No Item" message in ListView

Tags: android

I've created some composie UIs in my android apps and there are some ListView controls -among other controls- inside a view. Because of this, I have used "Activity" as my activity base class.

Now I need to display a simple message like "No Item" when the ListView that is bound to my adapter is empty. I know this is possible when using ListActivity but I'm not sure what's the best approach for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView : default text when no items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088711/android-listview-default-text-when-no-items)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're looking for the empty view of a `ListActivity`:

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

If you're using `ListView` you can use the method `setEmptyView()`:

[setEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View))

Comment: I already mentioned that I am using another base class, so this may not be applicable.

Comment: I see, nevertheless you can use the setEmptyView() method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View))

Comment: See my answer for using the `setEmptyView` method without a `ListActivity`

Answer (score 100):

You can have an empty view without a `ListActivity`! The correct method is as follows

First add an 'empty view' to your layout XML below your list

```
...
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
...
```

Next override the `onContentChanged` method of your activity and set the empty view of your list to your empty view:

```
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();

    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setEmptyView(empty);
}
```

That's it! Android will take care of hiding/showing the list and empty view when you update the adapter.

**The Magic**

Deciding whether the empty view is shown or not is handled by the superclass of `ListView`, `AdapterView`. `AdapterView` registers a `DataSetObserver` on the set adapter so it is notified whenever the data is changed. This triggers a call to `checkFocus` in `AdapterView` which contains the following lines

```
if (mEmptyView != null) {
    updateEmptyStatus((adapter == null) || adapter.isEmpty());
}
```

and sets the empty view visibility based on whether the adapter is empty or not.

Comment: It works, but I can't figure out what magic makes the TextView not displayed ?!

Comment: @DenisGL: The ListView takes care of hiding/showing the TextView according to whether the attached adapter has any items.

Comment: nice explanation of magic, what I suspected. If you're implementing your own adapter you can override the [isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEmpty()) method to return true/false based on whatever your criteria are for emptiness.

Comment: Code can be viewed online here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus%28boolean%29 for those interested.

Comment: I'm using a fragment so I put the `setEmptyView` inside `onCreateView()` method and it worked just fine

Comment: clever solution

Comment: How to use inside Fragment?

Answer (score 10):

Just combine your `ListView` with `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_empty"
    android:text="No Item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then check the count of items an chanche visibility on `ListView` accordingly:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setVisibility((adapter.isEmpty())?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
```

If you are using Custom Adapter, you can do this in the overridden `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Toast Message for this..

Check the Count of the Adapter value by `adapter.getCount()`

```
if(Adapter.getCount()!=0){
      List.setAdapter(Adapter); 
}else{
     Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "No Items Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Can't do this either. I may have more than one listview in a view so displaying a toast is not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

For the layout code by Joseph, you need to edit the @+id/list and @+id/empty to @android:id/***, like:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

This way, you even don't need to override the onContentChanged() function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this was using a ListFragment instead of a ListActivity. ListFragment has the following convenience method:

```
setEmptyText("My no items message...");
```

Besides, using a ListFragment class has other advantages. For example, the possibility to combine it with the new AppCompat library (which you cannot do with ListActivity because you have to extend from ActionBarActivity).