# android SimpleCursorAdapter no item msg

Tags: android, listings, simplecursoradapter

I have used to following code to display the favorite item listing. It has a deletion functionality through context menu.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .........................
    .........................

       wordDataHelper = new WordDataHelper(getApplicationContext());
        favCursor  = wordDataHelper.getCursorFav();
        startManagingCursor(favCursor);
        // Now create a new list adapter bound to the cursor.
        // SimpleListAdapter is designed for binding to a Cursor.
        favAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, // Context.
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                favCursor,                                              // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
                new String[] {WordDataHelper.ENGWORD},           // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});  // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those columns.

        // Bind to our new adapter.
        setListAdapter(favAdapter);

        list = getListView();


list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            // @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
                menu.add(0, CONTEXT_DELETE, 1, "Delete Item");
            }
        });

        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        list.setClickable(true);

        ..................
    ..................
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        final Long wordId = menuInfo.id;
        // selected_row = menuInfo.position;

        // To get the id of the clicked item in the list use menuInfo.id
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXT_DELETE:
            deleteRes(wordId);
            favCursor  = wordDataHelper.getCursorFav();
            ((SimpleCursorAdapter) favAdapter).changeCursor(favCursor);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        }


        return true;
    }
```

Everything is working fine. Now I want to display a "No favorite item" msg when there is no item to list. How to arrange it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Display "No Item" message in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565451/display-no-item-message-in-listview)

Comment: I have added list = getListView();
        View empty = (View) findViewById(R.layout.empty);
        list.setEmptyView(empty); where <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="@string/empty_fav"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
/> But nothing is appearing. whts the prob?