# ListView doesn't remove empty view on first data results, but does thereafter

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that is correctly displaying my empty view when it does not have data, according to this posts:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5565700/4527140

When the ListView is then populated with data the first time, it does not update and show the data. If I do something to cause the cursor to be reloaded, it then displays the data. But even trying to force a reload for that first population of the data doesn't remove the empty view.

In my code below, on the first run, the user will select a language, so in onResume, onLanguageChanged() will be called, which in turns calls restartLoader() on the cursor. But it continues to display the empty view.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity {

    private static String mLanguage;
    private MyFragment mMyFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLanguage = Utility.getActiveLanguageName(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myFragment =  ((MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my));
        if (mMyFragment == null) {
            mMyFragment = new MyFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_my, mMyFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_words);
        list.setEmptyView(empty);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkSetup(); //check initialization setup
        String activeLanguage = Utility.getActiveLanguageName(this);
        if (!activeLanguage.equals(mLanguage)) { //if language has changed, reload listview
            mLanguage = activeLanguage;
            mMyFragment.onLanguageChange();
        }
    }
}
```

MyFragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;
    private static final int LIST_LOADER = 0;
    private ListView mListView;
    private int mIndex = -1;
    private int mTop = 0;


    public DictionaryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //switch between different queries based on user selections

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                query,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mMyAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        if(mIndex!=-1) {
            mListView.setSelectionFromTop(mIndex, mTop);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mMyAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        if(mIndex!=-1) {
            mListView.setSelectionFromTop(mIndex, mTop);
        }
    }

    public void reloadData() {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, MyFragment.this);
    }

    public void onLanguageChange(){
        mIndex = 0;
        mTop = 0;
        reloadData();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The listview is properly refreshed on a language change later on. The problem occurs **only** on the first run.

I have tried all of the following in onLoadFinished(), with no change:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
mListView.invalidateViews();
mListView.refreshDrawableState();
```

Refreshing the list usually has a slight delay, where the list is set `GONE` and the spinner is set `VISIBLE` With this first load, there is no delay, no spinner, it just goes straight to the empty view.

With some more digging, I think the problem is the underlying data. During that initial setup process, data is being retrieved from the server and populating the tables. If I wait a few seconds on those setup screens, during which time the data is loaded in the background, then by the time I get back to my ListView, the query has results and they come up. So it seems it is an issue of the CursorAdapter updating with the data once it has been loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that mMyFragment.onLanguageChange() is working?

Comment: please provide code for onLanguageChange() method did you applay notifydatasetchangedmethod() ?

Comment: I've added the code above, and I am certain onLanguageChange() works.