# How to use setEmptyView() with custom list layout in ListFragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm using a paginator with a few `Fragments`.

I want to show a message when there are no entries in the list (`Fragment`).

I tried to use `Textview` with `android:id="@id/android:empty` but it doesn't work.

Custom list layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/label_value"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/title_time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

List adapter class:

```
public class JournalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;
    private final List<String> dates;

    public JournalAdapter(Context context, List<String> values,
            List<String> dates) {
        super(context, R.layout.layout_journal_list, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_journal_list, parent, false);

        TextView value = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label_glucose);
        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label_date);

        value.setText(values.get(position));
        date.setText(dates.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

List parsing method:

```
private void initListView() {
        values = dataSource.getAllValues();

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Value value : values) {
            values.add(Double.toString(value.getValue()));
            dates.add(secondsToDate(value.getDate()));
        }

        setListAdapter(new JournalAdapter(context, values, dates));

        listView = getListView();
        listView.setEmptyView(noItems("NO ITEMS"));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

`noItems` method:

```
private TextView noItems(String text) {
        TextView emptyView = new TextView(context);
        emptyView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        emptyView.setText(text);
        emptyView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        emptyView.setTextSize(20);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        return emptyView;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason for setting the visibility of the `TextView` that you create in the `noItems()` method to **View.GONE**?

Comment: I copy down this code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088711/android-listview-default-text-when-no-items.

By the way, I tried remove this line and also set to VISIBLE, but still the same.

Comment: Can you try setting the empty `TextView` only once(for example in the `onActivityCreated`) in your `ListFragment` and then simply update its text(look for the `TextView` with `findViewById()`(of course  adding an id(like `android.R.id.empty`)))?

Comment: If I correct understand you I can't update text using findviewById() method because Eclipse shows this error: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FragmentValue. 
P.S. FragmentValue is the name of the class.

Comment: Yes, use the `Activity`: `getActivity().findViewById`

Comment: It looks like now working. I changed a little bit noItems method and call it before initializing list view on onActivityCreated method. Thanks a lot, Man!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This worked for me (got the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088711/android-listview-default-text-when-no-items) asked by [William Remacle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406761/william-remacle)). What you might have missed is **adding the created `TextView` to the `ListView` layout parent** (second line of code from the bottom of the `noItems` method below):

In my `ListFragment` I used the following method to get a view for the empty view:

```
private TextView noItems(String text) {
    TextView emptyView = new TextView(getActivity());
    //Make sure you import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
    emptyView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //Instead of passing resource id here I passed resolved color 
    //That is, getResources().getColor((R.color.gray_dark))
    emptyView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_dark));
    emptyView.setText(text);
    emptyView.setTextSize(12);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
            | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //Add the view to the list view. This might be what you are missing
    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);

    return emptyView;
}
```

Then in the `onStart()` method of the the `ListFragment` set the the empty view:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setEmptyView(
            noItems(getResources().getString(R.string.widget_empty)));
}
```

Comment: This worked more reliably for me when inserting the `emptyView` as the first child: `((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView, 0);` so that it doesn't overlap the `ListView`.

Comment: It worked like a charme. I agree with @TalkLittle, it's far more reliable than using custom view into layout. Thank you!

Comment: After a tiring search... finally above solution worked for me! Thanks @fahmy!

Answer (score 2):

```
  android:id="@android:id/empty"
```

and not

```
  android:id="@id/android:empty"
```

Comment: Still the same. 

By the way, Android documentation writes @id/android:empty, not @android:id/empty. Reference - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html