# Custom empty view for ListFragment in XML

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to modify existing code while being new to Android. Let me know if any of the concepts or assumptions I'm explaining don't make sense in this world!

My goal is to define a layout in XML for the empty view of my list view. Today, we have this functionality by programmatically tweaking the default empty view in `onActivityCreated` of my `CustomListFragment` deriving from `ListFragment`:

```
setEmptyText(getResources().getString(R.string.listview_empty));
TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) getListView().getEmptyView();
emptyTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.listview_empty_text_size));
emptyTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_empty_text));
```

I would rather define the styling of my empty view in XML. It's cleaner, and I would be able to use a custom layout while now it only allows for a single string.

It seemed to rely on a default listview layout (as I couldn't find any `inflate` in the fragment code), which contains an empty text view, a progress indicator, etc. I tried to provide my custom layout; here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No items to show."/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And now I override `onCreateView` in my `CustomListFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

I removed the piece of code I posted above from `onActivityCreated`.

Now, I am getting a crash because `ListFragment`'s `mProgressContainer` is null. It is originally set in `ensureList()` by:

```
mProgressContainer = root.findViewById(INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID);
```

Am I supposed to define a "Progress Container" control in my custom layout? It looks to me like it's not the right approach as I'd need to give it an `id` set to `INTERNAL_PROGRESS_CONTAINER_ID`.

What's the recommended way for me to provide a custom XML-defined view for the empty text situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) for ListFragment's onCreateView() says:

> If you are overriding this method with your own custom content, consider including the standard layout list_content in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard behavior of ListFragment. In particular, this is currently the only way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.

Examining the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ListFragment.java#380) of that `ensureList()` method shows that if you are using a custom  view, it's more than a consideration: it looks like you *have* to include the standard `list_content` layout, otherwise it will blow up when looking for a progress container.

However, even if you do include:

```
    <include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
```

in your XML, and you define your own custom empty view with an ID of `android.R.id.empty`, you'll run into a problem with using your own empty view. The code in `ensureList()` prefers the default layout's empty view over your own:

```
        mStandardEmptyView = (TextView)root.findViewById(
                com.android.internal.R.id.internalEmpty);
        if (mStandardEmptyView == null) {
            mEmptyView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        } else {
            mStandardEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I also tried setting the empty view directly on my list view, i.e.:

```
getListView().setEmptyView(myCustomEmptyView)
```

But that had problems too, as the list fragment doesn't know to hide the empty view when it's showing the built-in progress container.

My conclusion is that if you want to define your own custom empty view, you can't take advantage of ListFragment's built-in behaviours or methods such as `setListAdapter()` and `setListShown()`, and you have to manage the visibility of a  progress container and empty view yourself.

Comment: There's some related discussions in [Android Issue #21742](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21742)

Comment: Thanks for digging into this.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use setEmptyView rather than setEmptyText.

This related question and answer shows how to use a custom view that you can set using `setEmptyView` https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990955/443900

summary is to do something like:

```
// if you're using a ListFragment
// do this inside onActivityCreated 
View  emptyView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null);

((ViewGroup)getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Save my day! :)