# Show empty view for ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I've got a `ListView` in my application that's rendered in a `ListFragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`using `setListAdapter()`. Passed in to this `setListAdapter()`are my implementation of `ArrayAdapter`. At some times this adapter can be empty, and that's fine, but at those moments I would like to show a message in the list telling  that there are no items, instead of just an empty view. However I don't really know how to achieve this, as for I have researched most people to show lists in a `ListActivity`and by doing that you can `setEmptyView()` but this doesn't seem doable when using a `ListFragment`. Another way of doing this was to change view in the `ListFragment` if the `ArrayAdapter` has no item's in it, then change view to another showing the message, but this seems to me a bit hacky.

Whats really the proper way of doing what I want to achieve?

Tried to `setEmptyView()` to my `ListView` but that didn't work either, see code on how views are inflated in my `ListFragment`:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
        listView.setEmptyView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_missing, null));
        return listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        MyItemArrayAdapter adapter = new MyItemArrayAdapter(getActivity());

        // Populate adapter with items...

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't this result in the empty view beeing shown if no items exists in my adapter?

Comment: try putting background image for ListView inside xml. If no item, show background image, if there is item, make background color. It is how google message app does

Comment: ListActivity has no setEmptyView method. The method is part of ListView

Comment: However this has issues and will not always work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty/28188185#28188185

Comment: See updated question on how I'm trying to `setEmptyView()` to my `ListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Try putting `backgroundImage` for `ListView` inside `xml`. If no item, show `backgroundImage`, if there is item, put background color.

**2)** You can also do what as @kgandroid [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771568/showing-empty-view-when-listview-is-empty/28188185#28188185) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15990955/3736955), `setEmptyView()` which you set custom view.

**Example:**

[image]

**Another:**

[image]

Comment: I'd like to use a background image for listview, but can't get the resolutions right for that image. It will always look different for different devices and there screen resolutions. I guess I need to create a nine patch image but this start to look overkill for tha things I want to achieve. Then I tried to `setEmptyView` instead but that didnt work either. See updated question for the code.

Comment: @Robert this guy used it in ListFragment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990955/3736955. Try `TextView emptyView=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_missing, null)`, `(ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);` `listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);`

Comment: that did acually work, must have been the `((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);` that was missing

Comment: just for curiosity, how do you made the background images for the list views so they look good on most devices? I still think using background images are the cleanest solution.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, i saw them in apps. Probably using different resolutions of image (xxhdpi, xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi...)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your adapter to show the layout `R.layout.list_items_missing` when `(item == null)` instead of inflating the normal custom list item layout that you implement.

Something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
   ViewHolder holder; //asuming you have this in your custom adapter
if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
  if(MyItemArrayList.get(position)!=null)
{
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item,
                parent, false);
else
{
convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_missing,
                    parent, false);

}
//the rest of the adapter logic
}
```